# Associated records not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many, associations

In my Rails 4 application I have users, each of which can belong to any number of organizations but the relationship also has a role of either `'member'` or `'administrator'`.

I have three models: `Organization`, `User`, and `UserOrganizationRelationship` containing `user_id:integer`, `organization_id:integer`, and `relationship:string`

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_organization_relationships
    has_many :users, :through => :user_organization_relationships

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_organization_relationships
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_organization_relationships
    has_many :organizations, through: :user_organization_relationships
end

class UserOrganizationRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :organization

    self.primary_key = :user_id

    Administrator = 'administrator'
    Member = 'member'
end
```

I created a form to be able to modify each member's relationship type

```
= form_for @organization do |f|
    = f.fields_for :user_organization_relationship do |u|
        = u.label :relationship, @organization.users[u.index].username
        = u.select :relationship, options_for_select([UserOrganizationRelationship::Administrator, UserOrganizationRelationship::Member])
```

The problem I'm having is that when the user submits the form, the records in `user_organization_relationship` are not updated, I also don't get any errors. Here's the controller which receives the post data:

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
    ...
    def update
        if @organization.update!(organization_params)
            redirect_to @organization, notice: 'Organization was successfully updated.'
        else
            render action: 'edit'
        end
    end

    private
        def organization_params
            params.require(:organization).permit(user_organization_relationships_attributes: [:id, :user_id, :organization_id, :relationship])
        end
    ...
end
```

Debugging the update method shows that the parameters get through both the post data and the `organization_params` filter.

Comment: Is that a typo in your `organization_params` method? you have `user_organization_replationship` instead of `user_organization_relationship`

Comment: Also according to rails convention, `has_many` association name should be plural. In your case it should be `user_association_relationships`

Comment: Good eye! I changed the typo and pluralized the association, unfortunately it didn't change the situation.

Comment: Use @organization.update_attributes(organization_params).

Comment: Thanks @Emu, that too didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Ok, looks like one of those changes actually did fix the problem however I wasn't setting the selected value properly. Ugh. Thanks, if someone wants to write out an answer I'll get you some points.